# Polymer. How to reload iron-ajax "onpage show" event?

Tags: javascript, polymer

can you tell me how can i reload an iron-ajax when i opened a page.
For example:
I have page /news. When i clicked for this page i am opened element:

```
<dom-module id="my-news">
  <template id="app">
    <iron-ajax id="ajax_list"
            auto
            url="http://--------------/books"
            last-response="{{data}}"
            handleAs="json"
            on-response="handleResponse">
    </iron-ajax>
                    <iron-list id="news_list" items="[[data]]">
                          <template >
                            <paper-item  on-tap="open_news">[[item.name]]          </paper-item>
                          </template>
                    </iron-list>

  </template>
<script>
Polymer({
        is: 'my-news',
       }, 
....
</script>
```

If at this point to add news, the list is not updated. It is updated only when I press F5 and iron-ajax will work again.
I am create a function like this:

```
ready: function(){
    var _this_ = this;
    function(){this.ajax_list.generateRequest();}, 5000)
 }
```

But this is not exit

Answer (score 1):

In order to work, your function need to get the `iron-ajax` instance, and for that you need to use `this.$` instead of `this`. You also need to bind the function with `bind(this)` in order to pass the element instance to the callback.

Something like that:

`ready: function(){
    var _this_ = this;
    function(){ this.$.ajax_list.generateRequest() }.bind(this), 5000)
},`